# Circumcentre of triangles in a quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral

Suppose the diagonals of a quadrilateral ABCD meet at a point O; prove that the *circumcentres* of the 4 triangles OAB,OBC,OCD, and ODA form a parallelogram.

Comment: Show us what you've tried!

Comment: i joined the circumcentre to the vertices of the respective triangles.

Comment: and since the vertically opposite angles made by diagonals are equal the angle subtended at the circumcentre of opposite triangles are equal.

Comment: also the sides of quadrilateral formed by joining the circumcentres are perpendicular to diagonals. @Peterix

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that any of the perpendicular bisector lines drawn will be used to determine the circum-centers of two adjacent triangles. For example, $L$ will be used to determined the circum-centers of $\triangle AOD$ and $\triangle DOC$.

[image]

The red line is parallel to the corresponding red dotted line. The same is true for the green colored pair.

Comment: but why wont be the green line perpendicular to diagonal

Comment: The green lines are perpendicular to the other diagonal AC.